# shall I pass an object or a primitive?

Tags: javascript, performance

Consider I need a  value of some object's property in the function. Whenever I  have choice to  pass between  functions a primitive value or an object - which  one shall I choose? Does it influence a performance at all? I know that objects in javascript are passed by  reference and primitives by value and actually I can  extract  a value before passing it to  some  function  and also can pass an object  and get the  value inside the  function. Will it make any  difference?

Comment: General rule: don't worry too much about performance until it becomes a measurable problem.  Write code that makes sense to you first of all.

Comment: Modern Javascript engines do so much optimisation behind the scenes, you'll hardly be able to make a dent in it with such micro-optimisations.

Comment: unless you're doing a loop (or more than one) than end up iterating 10M+ times which contains very few instructions, you don't have to worry about this, this is way too low level to have any impact :)

Comment: Need to realize that objects are passed by reference not by value

Comment: @charlietfl: Need to realise that objects are reference values that are passed by value just like everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Consider I need a value of some object's property in the function.

Does/should the function know that it is an object's property, or does it only need the value? Does the function need to set the property, or does it only need the property value? Does the function always need the property value? Does the function need multiple properties of the object?

Choose whatever makes sense.

> Does it influence a performance at all?

Hardly.

Answer (score 2):

From the performance standpoint, there's no difference at all.

Given functions like these:

```
function bar(y) {
    return y.x + "A";
}

function foo(x) {
    return x + "A";
}
```

let's compare the generated code (`d8 --print_code`) for both:

```
kind = FUNCTION
name = foo
Instructions (size = 140)
 44  ff7510         push [rbp+0x10]
 47  48b8917b41caf2330000 REX.W movq rax,0x33f2ca417b91    ;; object: 0x33f2ca417b91 <String[1]: A>
 57  5a             pop rdx
 58  e8010efbff     call 0x2cdacea17520     ;; debug: statement 19
                                            ;; debug: position 28
                                            ;; code: BINARY_OP_IC, UNINITIALIZED (id = 7)
 63  90             nop
 64  48bb114b30dff2130000 REX.W movq rbx,0x13f2df304b11    ;; object: 0x13f2df304b11 Cell for 6144
 74  83430bd1       addl [rbx+0xb],0xd1
 78  791f           jns 111  (0x2cdacea6674f)
 80  50             push rax
 81  e82a45fdff     call InterruptCheck  (0x2cdacea3ac60)    ;; code: BUILTIN
 86  58             pop rax
 87  48bb114b30dff2130000 REX.W movq rbx,0x13f2df304b11    ;; object: 0x13f2df304b11 Cell for 6144
 97  49ba0000000000180000 REX.W movq r10,0x180000000000
107  4c895307       REX.W movq [rbx+0x7],r10
111  488be5         REX.W movq rsp,rbp      ;; debug: statement 35
                                            ;; js return
```

and

```
kind = FUNCTION
name = bar
Instructions (size = 164)
 44  488b4510       REX.W movq rax,[rbp+0x10]
 48  488bd0         REX.W movq rdx,rax
 51  48b9a1d742caf2330000 REX.W movq rcx,0x33f2ca42d7a1    ;; object: 0x33f2ca42d7a1 <String[1]: x>
 61  e89e00fdff     call 0x2cdacea36940     ;; debug: statement 57
                                            ;; debug: position 65
                                            ;; code: LOAD_IC, UNINITIALIZED (id = 11)
 66  50             push rax
 67  48b8917b41caf2330000 REX.W movq rax,0x33f2ca417b91    ;; object: 0x33f2ca417b91 <String[1]: A>
 77  5a             pop rdx
 78  e86d0cfbff     call 0x2cdacea17520     ;; debug: position 68
                                            ;; code: BINARY_OP_IC, UNINITIALIZED (id = 7)
 83  90             nop
 84  48bb214b30dff2130000 REX.W movq rbx,0x13f2df304b21    ;; object: 0x13f2df304b21 Cell for 6144
 94  83430bd1       addl [rbx+0xb],0xd1
 98  791f           jns 131  (0x2cdacea668e3)
100  50             push rax
101  e89643fdff     call InterruptCheck  (0x2cdacea3ac60)    ;; code: BUILTIN
106  58             pop rax
107  48bb214b30dff2130000 REX.W movq rbx,0x13f2df304b21    ;; object: 0x13f2df304b21 Cell for 6144
117  49ba0000000000180000 REX.W movq r10,0x180000000000
127  4c895307       REX.W movq [rbx+0x7],r10
131  488be5         REX.W movq rsp,rbp      ;; debug: statement 75
                                            ;; js return
```

As you can see, `bar` contains one extra function call (`LOAD_IC`, which is the dot) and has 24 more assembly instructions. This is not something you should worry about.

This is the code that calls `foo(obj.x)`:

```
48b981d712a7a60d0000 REX.W movq rcx,0xda6a712d781    ;; object: 0xda6a712d781 <String[3]: foo>
488b5627       REX.W movq rdx,[rsi+0x27]
e83a03fdff     call 0x169fb62368c0     ;; debug: statement 111
                                       ;; code: contextual, LOAD_IC, UNINITIALIZED
50             push rax
49ba214140cc39180000 REX.W movq r10,0x1839cc404121    ;; object: 0x1839cc404121 <undefined>
4152           push r10
48b9c1d712a7a60d0000 REX.W movq rcx,0xda6a712d7c1    ;; object: 0xda6a712d7c1 <String[3]: obj>
488b5627       REX.W movq rdx,[rsi+0x27]
e81a03fdff     call 0x169fb62368c0     ;; debug: position 115
                                       ;; code: contextual, LOAD_IC, UNINITIALIZED
488bd0         REX.W movq rdx,rax
48b9a1d712a7a60d0000 REX.W movq rcx,0xda6a712d7a1    ;; object: 0xda6a712d7a1 <String[1]: x>
e88803fdff     call 0x169fb6236940     ;; debug: position 118
                                       ;; code: LOAD_IC, UNINITIALIZED (id = 46)
50             push rax
4b8d1464       REX.W leaq rdx,[r12+r12*2]
488b7c2410     REX.W movq rdi,[rsp+0x10]
e8b9f7faff     call 0x169fb6215d80     ;; code: CALL_IC, DEFAULT
```

And this is `bar(obj)`:

```
8b981d7a2f60c3e0000 REX.W movq rcx,0x3e0cf6a2d781    ;; object: 0x3e0cf6a2d781 <String[3]: bar>
488b5627       REX.W movq rdx,[rsi+0x27]
e83a03fdff     call 0x35b86e8368c0     ;; debug: statement 125
                                       ;; code: contextual, LOAD_IC, UNINITIALIZED
50             push rax
49ba214160ee911c0000 REX.W movq r10,0x1c91ee604121    ;; object: 0x1c91ee604121 <undefined>
4152           push r10
48b9e1d7a2f60c3e0000 REX.W movq rcx,0x3e0cf6a2d7e1    ;; object: 0x3e0cf6a2d7e1 <String[3]: obj>
488b5627       REX.W movq rdx,[rsi+0x27]
e81a03fdff     call 0x35b86e8368c0     ;; debug: position 129
                                       ;; code: contextual, LOAD_IC, UNINITIALIZED
50             push rax
4b8d1464       REX.W leaq rdx,[r12+r12*2]
488b7c2410     REX.W movq rdi,[rsp+0x10]
e8cbf7faff     call 0x35b86e815d80     ;; code: CALL_IC, DEFAULT
```

Comment: Could you add calls (`bar(o)`, `foo(o.x)`) to the code?

Answer (score 1):

It is always good to test if in doubt. I've prepared [jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/object-or-primitive) to compare both cases using same calls as **georg** used with dump.

[image: test results]

As you can see the only visible difference is present in Gecko engine but I think it is still insignificant because we are talking about ~7M - ~26M operations per second.

If you are looking for optimisations this is not a good place to check.